# Convert Oracle query using to_date() to SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I would like to convert the following Oracle statements to SQL Server statements:

```
SELECT CAST(e.A_D_V AS DATE) + TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(f.A_T_24, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'HH24')) / 24  Per
```

The A_D_V column has a date type  in the DB 
The A_T_24 column has a number(2,0) date type in the DB.

I have tried to following, but the query gives many errors

```
CAST(e.A_D_V AS DATE) + ' ' + try_CONVERT(char(8), f.A_T_24,108) / 24  Per
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code in SQL Server.

```
declare @T VARCHAR(30) = '10:34:54'
declare @D varchar(30) = '2020-05-04'
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(@d as Date), ' ', CAST(DATEPART(HH,CAST(@T AS Time))  AS DECIMAL(4,2))/ 24) as Datevalue 

+---------------------+
|      Datevalue      |
+---------------------+
| 2020-05-04 0.416666 |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comment, but i get the error: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: To update on the comment above, i fixed that issue. I would like the outcome to be 2020-05-06 00:00:01.